# Magento 2.2.4 - Couldn't override block class

Tags: blocks, magento2.2.4, class

I am trying to override the `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable` class.

I have added a preference in `app/code/vendor/module/etc/di.xml` file.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" type="vendor\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" />
</config>
```

After running the `setup:di:compile` command, I noticed that Magento is still using the old one.

I have added preferences number of times but had experienced such behavior.

Comment: is worth mentioning if you haven't done so run setup:upgrade, clear:cache, cache:flush, setup:static  there is a good blog here just in case:https://magenticians.com/magento-2-override-block/

Comment: @JulianoVargas I had run all the commands.

Comment: you have to change functionality by plugin method  preference not works all time

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code and replace the vendor and module name with your vendor name and module name:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" />
</config>
```

Comment: Is it different from the one i have mentioned?

Comment: Did you created any module with namespace vendor and module name ConfigurableProduct?

Comment: Ofcourse, i have it  in a separate module.

Comment: What is the name of that module? Can you give me the exact path of that module?

Comment: I have updated the module and vendor name on my end in di.xml.

Comment: What is the exact path of Configurable.php of your module? Check the case sensitive as well.

Comment: Checked it twice

Comment: You have put vendor which is case-sensitive. Folder name is vendor or Vendor? If vendor then change the name to Vendor and then update the di.xml to capital V.